# How do calculate $\int{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}}dx$?

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate the following integral

$$\int{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}}dx$$

The method suggested by an integral calculator seems very complicated.

Comment: Looks doable with trig substitution.  $x=\sin\theta$

Comment: Substitute $x=2t/(1+t^2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1} dx$$
Let $x=\sin t, dx=\cos t dt$, then $$I=\int  [\csc t-\sin t] dt = -\ln[\csc t+ \cot t] +\cos t+C$$ $$=-\ln[1+\sqrt{1-x^2}]+\ln x+\sqrt{1-x^2}+C$$